# How to make multiple socket DDE & RTD requests faster

Tags: python, performance, sockets, winapi, rtd

So, basically I have a python program and I need to intercept 137 DDE & RTD signals that are feeding excel files. I'm doing this by using a socket with the following code:

```
import socket
import win32api

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 12002))

s.sendall(str.encode('COT$S|' + stock + '#'))
data = s.recv(32768)
```

But, when I run this 137 times, it takes 27 seconds to finish, but I need something between 5s and 10s. So, I've tried to use multiprocessing, but, it starts taking infinity amounts of ram of my computer, until it crashes.
Is there anything that I can do to optimize this code? Thanks!

Comment: Have you used `multiprocessing.Pool`? That would be my suggestion. If you search for examples, there should be plenty for your use-case. However, the upper bound will still be the duration of a single transaction: have you measured how long a single `sendall/recv` takes?

Comment: I was using `multiprocessing.Process`, with `multiprocessing.Manager`. And yes, I've measuread it, It takes about 100ms, mostly on the `recv`. I'll take a look on the `multiprocessing.Pool`, thank you for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `multiprocessing.Pool`. Having had some time on hand, I did some mock test, and this works. Tune to fit your needs.

As it is, it will use a pool of 5 workers to cycle through each item in the `stocks` list, so memory consumption should be in check, yet execution should be quite fast. You can adjust the pool size, of course.

```
import socket
import win32api
from multiprocessing import Pool

stocks = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE']  # just a sample list

def network_op(stock):
    print('Running ' + stock)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 12002))
    s.sendall(str.encode('COT$S|' + stock + '#'))
    d = s.recv(32768)
    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(network_op, stocks))
```